# Where does convolution fit into tracking fluorescent photons using MC models?

Tags: convolution

I have been reading this old paper by Steven Jacques, a titan in the world of using Monte-Carlo methods for photon propagation and distributions.

https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-28-20-4286

For the moment, I have a pretty solid grasp how to continue with my research. However, there is one element that has me perplexed. The author states this powerful formula:

$$
F(\lambda,r) = \int_0^D\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \psi(r',z')\beta(\lambda,z) \circledast E(\lambda,\sqrt(r^2+r'^2-2rr'cos\theta')
$$
Which shows up again and again in more recent papers. 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9203387

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24307289

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21945055

And it seems to work well enough to last the ages, so I would like to implement it myself. However, I get confused by the convolution operator presented above. $\psi$ is just in terms of the depth of the laser and corresponds to the excitation laser being launched. This has spatial dependence hence r and z. So we can approximate this as a 3D matrix. $\beta$ is by the layer, so it depends on how many layers we want to simulate. In skin, we could  have 4 layers. E is the escape function, which means how many photons reach the surface of the medium when launched isotropically from a depth in the medium. E and $\beta$ also depend on the wavelength and are experimentally validated. My BIG question, though, is how to do the convolution to both  sides, and what would that actually represent.

We summarize, we have $\psi$ as a 3D matrix, $\beta$ as a vector of equivalent depth and E as a 3D matrix the same size as $\psi$.